# How to display error validation from backend to frontend in Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

How can I display errors validation from backend to frontend in Angular ???

I got movie title error validation showed up but don't know how to get reviews validation of the movie show up.

Here's my model.js

```
const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Customer name is required"],
        minlength: [3, "Customer name must be a minimum of 3 characters"]
    },
    stars: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
comment: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Review is required"],
    minlength: [3, "Review must be a minimum of 3 characters"]
}
})
```

and this is my controllers.js:

```
createMovie: function (req, res) {
    Movie.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                message: "Error!",
                error: error,
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                message: "Success!",
                added: true,
                data: data
            });
        }
    })
},
```

This is my components.ts:

```
error = "";

  onSubmit() {
    let observable = this._httpService.createMovie(this.newMovie);
    observable.subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.error) {
        this.error = data.error;
        this._router.navigate(["movies/new"]);
      } else {
        this.getMoviesFromService();
        this._router.navigate([""]);
      }
    });
  }
```

And here's how i display my movie title error validation from backend.
Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: Hey there, Ill assume that you are correctly sending. So what I understand from you component.ts code is that you are getting the error from the backend as a key inside the data? (Not sure about this please confirm). I.e: if you want to get error from lets say firebase, django apis you can add another parameter to subscribe to get the errors. I do not know if you are aware of it. If not let me  know so I write my approach to what I think can work in your case. @nathannewyen

Answer (score 0):

Please add a console.log(error) inside your controller and see what is inside it.
As I remember I am not so sure but error.data.message will have the validation message. So in the response, you have to send it to the frontend. Then you can show it as you need.